# Trouble with dns and debian update

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, apt

I tried to update my debian dreamplug server with the command running as root apt-get update and recieved these errors.

```
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates Release.gpg                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/main Translation-en_US                                                                          
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/contrib Translation-en_US                                                                       
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://security.debian.org lenny/updates/non-free Translation-en_US                                                                      
  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'
Err http://www.backports.org lenny-backports Releasegpg                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'
Err http://www.backports.org lenny-backports/main Translation-en_US                                      
  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'
Err http://www.backports.org lenny-backports/contrib Translation-en_US                                   
  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'
Err http://www.backports.org lenny-backports/non-free Translation-en_US                                  
  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny Release.gpg                                                           
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/main Translation-en_US              
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/contrib Translation-en_US           
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Err http://ftp.us.debian.org lenny/non-free Translation-en_US          
  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'
Err http://http.us.debian.org stable Release.gpg                       
  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'
Err http://http.us.debian.org stable/main Translation-en_US            
  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'
Err http://http.us.debian.org stable/contrib Translation-en_US         
  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'
Err http://http.us.debian.org stable/non-free Translation-en_US        
  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done                                          
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'ftp.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'http.us.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/lenny/updates/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'security.debian.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.backports.org/debian/dists/lenny-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.backports.org/debian/dists/lenny-backports/main/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.backports.org/debian/dists/lenny-backports/contrib/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'

W: Failed to fetch http://www.backports.org/debian/dists/lenny-backports/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US.gz  Could not resolve 'www.backports.org'

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I am able to ping ip addresses but not namespaces.  Can't seem to figure out the problem.  My /etc/resolv.conf file contains 
nameserver 192.168.1.2
which is my router.

Comment: Note: I purposely put a 'd' and deleted the 'h' in http becuase stackoverflow won't let me hyperlink more than 2 addresses.

Comment: I removed the 'd's and added the 'h's back in.

Comment: Use archive.debian.org. That's where old Debian dists go to die. Or at least sit in perpetuity. And remember, you're never getting another security update until you upgrade to something current.

Comment: @MichaelLowman: It's not like resolving DNS has anything to do with debian lenny being obsolete. (even though he still won't be able to update afterwards)

Comment: Have you tried changing your /etc/resolv.conf as I suggested? They are the google DNS servers.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

You DNS server might be broken. Also I can't seem to open those files. There was a topic recently on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/404806/debian-lenny-repositories-vanished). Lenny is End Of Life.